# why is the variable not changing from upper to lower case in the data frame in r but it changed in the console?

Tags: r, dataframe, console, rename, data-cleaning

To easily call functions in R i changed all variable names from upper case (WorldwideBox Ofice)  to lower case (worldwidebox office) and replaced all spaces with an underscore (worldwidebox_office) while the code successfully ran in the console the variable names have however remained the same in the data frame.[enter image description here]

this is the code i used to make the change

```
#data cleaning and manipulation-  substitute space in variable with underscore
#change variable names to lower case

names(film) <- gsub(' ','_',names(film))
names(film) <- tolower(names(film))
names(film)
```

I was expecting something like this in the data frame:

```
rank, year, movie, worldwidebox_office, domesticbox_office, internationalbox_office
```

But this what i got (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p18I8.png)

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: The `glimpse` you show in your output shows the cleaned names. If you want the table view to update you should redraw it with `View(film)`. Form what you've shown it looks like everything worked correctly. You just had stale data in the viewer.

Comment: Oh thank you MrFlick your right